# Monitor ppp0 traffic usage with Linux

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, 3g

Hey I'm developing a 3G connected device with a raspberry Pi. My mobile provider allows me to use 50 MB/month.

This device will be installed somewhere nobody can have physically access to.
My concern is to avoid data traffic overuse. I need a tool to measure all the accumulated traffic going through (in and out) the ppp0 interface in order to disconnect the interface until next month if the 50MB limit is reached.

I tried with `ifconfig` but since I have some disconnections the counter is always rested at each reconnection.

I tried `ntop` and `iftop` but from what I understood these are tools for measuring real-time traffic.

I'm really looking for some kind of cumulative traffic use, like we usually can find on smartphones.

Any idea?

Comment: Ask here: http://serverfault.com/about

Comment: Thanks. Question duplicated here http://serverfault.com/questions/641408/monitor-ppp0-traffic-usage-with-linux

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in to IPtraf :)

I'm not sure if it will go in to enough detail for you as it is relatively lightweight, though it may not be wise to go too heavy on the raspberry pi processor. You could also try looking around for netflow or SNMP based solutions, though I think that might be overkill.

Good luck!